# How to convert array to url parameter?

Tags: php

This is my array:

```
$url_parameter = Array ( 'country' => 'USA', 'city' => 'WDC', 'from' => 'Japan' );
```

I want to covert it so that output is:

```
country=USA&city=WDC&from=Japan
```

Is there any easy code to do this task?

Comment: could you please give me the link of answer?

Comment: http_build_query($url_parameter), help on php.net : https://php.net/http_build_query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$url_parameter = Array ( 'country' => 'USA', 'city' => 'WDC', 'from' => 'Japan' );

echo http_build_query($url_parameter) . "\n";
echo http_build_query($url_parameter, '', '&amp;');
```